# How to authenticate user in gatsby

Tags: javascript, reactjs, authentication, gatsby

I have followed [**this**](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/authentication-tutorial/) tutorial to implement authentication in my `gatsby` project. The problem is I have first setup the project and the routing is made from the `pages` folder and then I have implemented the above auth code but it still taking the routes from the **pages** folder and not from the **app.js** file. Could someone please help how can I route my components from the **app.js** instead of using from **pages** folder.

This is my gatsby-nodejs file

```
// Implement the Gatsby API “onCreatePage”. This is
// called after every page is created.
exports.onCreatePage = async ({ page, actions }) => {
  const { createPage } = actions

  // page.matchPath is a special key that's used for matching pages
  // only on the client.
  if (page.path.match(/^\/app/)) {
    page.matchPath = "/app/*"

    // Update the page.
    createPage(page)
  }
}
```

here is **src/pages.app.js**

```
import React from "react"
import { Router } from "@reach/router"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import Home from '../components/dashboard/home/container'
import Login from '../components/marketing/home/pulsemetrics'
import { isLoggedIn } from "../services/auth"


console.log('vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv')

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, location, ...rest }) => {
    console.log('hjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii')
  if (!isLoggedIn() && location.pathname !== `/app/login`) {
    // If the user is not logged in, redirect to the login page.
    navigate(`/app/login`)
    return null
  }

  return <Component {...rest} />
}

const App = () => (
  <Layout>
    <Router>
      <PrivateRoute path="/ddddddddddddddddddd" component={Home} />
      <Login path="/" />
    </Router>
  </Layout>
)

export default App
```

Comment: Can we have a look at your `src/pages/app.js` file?

Comment: @etarhan Thank you I have updated my question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The paths that you have in your `App.js` should have `/app/` prepended in front of them since your PrivateRoute logic uses that to check for a login. Furthermore what your gatsby-node.js file is really saying is that for routes starting with app it should create a new page. Your `src/pages/app.js` has the task to define how these pages should be created (since they won't be the usual generated static pages by gatsby)

```js
import React from "react"
import { Router } from "@reach/router"
import Layout from "../components/layout"
import Home from '../components/dashboard/home/container'
import Login from '../components/marketing/home/pulsemetrics'
import { isLoggedIn } from "../services/auth"


console.log('vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv')

const PrivateRoute = ({ component: Component, location, ...rest }) => {
    console.log('hjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjjiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiiii')
  if (!isLoggedIn() && location.pathname !== `/app/login`) {
    // If the user is not logged in, redirect to the login page.
    navigate(`/app/login`)
    return null
  }

  return <Component {...rest} />
}

const App = () => (
  <Layout>
    <Router>
      <PrivateRoute path="/app/home" component={Home} />
      <Login path="/app/login" />
    </Router>
  </Layout>
)

export default App
```

Read the gatsby client-only routes [documentation](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/building-apps-with-gatsby/#client-only-routes--user-authentication) for reference or have a look at this github [issue](https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby/issues/8894)

Comment: I tried this. When I hit `/app/home` it does not render anything. `Gatsby.js development 404 page`

Comment: No it is also not working. Actually only that pages are working which I have defined inside my **pages** folder. It still taking from the pages folder. I need to render them from the above routing

Comment: ***My guess is that what you have in your pages folder other than app.js, index.js and 404.js is somehow causing problems*** yes I have other files in my pages folder which creates routes.

Comment: Thank you very much. I think I am close to the target. I owe you one

Comment: Hi just a small thing. My routes are prefixed with **`/app`** I don't want that. I only need `/`. How can I do this?

Comment: Hi etarhan Can I use `this.props.location` in `layout` file? If you know the answer I will raise a question

Comment: Thanks here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55631403/how-to-get-pathname-in-the-layout-file-in-gatsby